# Licensing for redistribution

Tags: license

Can I redistribute ubuntu if I install docker engine on it?
does installing apt package consider to be modification of the ubuntu software and require ubuntu pro from Canonical?

Comment: You have to ask the Canonical legal team for this..

Comment: You can modify and redistribute as much as you like...but you cannot call it Ubuntu anymore. It's not. Your custom respin can only claim to be "based upon Ubuntu" and no more. It cannot use Ubuntu trademarks nor official Ubuntu support channels. There may be simpler alternatives, like Preseed files and install scripts, to accomplish your goal while keeping Ubuntu .